# Navigation in Local Frame (odom frame)

Tags: ros, navigation, control, odometry, tf2

I am working on a control related task - a docking procedure for an AMR to be specific. That task requires my robot's pose information throughout the planned path as it moves to the goal/docking station.

By many users in forums and [REP105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), it is recommended that these kind of operations should be done in local frame, `/odom` frame that is:

> The odom frame is useful as an accurate, short-term local reference,
> but drift makes it a poor frame for long-term reference.

My question is, would taking `/odom` as reference frame for my "high-precision required" application be any different than doing it with taking `/map` as reference frame, which is what I am doing now? Because even with the `/odom` taken as reference frame, due to hierarchy of frames being `/map --> /odom --> /base_link` I am still dependent to `/map` frame right?

So how using `/odom` instead of `/map` makes any difference on my approach? If it does, would that make this "local planning" control task perform better?